# unknown vector size python

Tags: python, matlab, vector

I have a matlab code that I'm trying to translate in python. 
I'm new on python but I have been able to answer a lot of questions googling a little bit.
But now, I'm trying to figure out the following:
I have a for loop when I apply different things on each column, but you don't know the number of columns. For example.
In matlab, nothing easier than this:

```
    for n = 1:size(x,2); y(n) = mean(x(:,n)); end
```

But I have no idea how to do it on python when, for example, the number of columns is 1, because I can't do x[:,1] in python.
Any idea?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/). It is a python bindings for high-performance math library written in C. I believe it has the same concepts of matrix slice operations, and it is significantly faster than the same code written in pure python (in most cases).

Regarding your example, I think the closest would be something using [`numpy.mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html).

In pure python it is hard to calculate mean of column, but it you are able to transpose the matrix you could do it using something like this:

```
# there are no builtin avg function
def avg(lst):
    return sum(lst)/len(lst)

rows = list(avg(row) for row in a)
```

Comment: Thanks. mean() was only an example. But for the main question, I already use numpy but if I creat an array, for example, x = array([1,2,3,4]), I can't do x[:,1]. It makes no sense for this case but it's just an example.

Comment: @tete [`numpy.matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) should do it

Comment: @tete `numpy` *does* support `x[:, 1]`; check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you use numpy you can use x[:,1], and also you get other data structures (vectors instead of lists), the main difference between matlab and numpy is that matlab uses matrices for calculations and numpy uses vectors, but you get used to it, I think [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users) will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

this is one way to do it

```
from numpy import *
x=matrix([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])
[mean(x[:,n]) for n in range(shape(x)[1])]

# [1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
```